# Can only boot GUI in Recovery Mode (Black Screen with underscore otherwise)

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, intel-graphics

I am using Ubuntu 22.04, and as of last night the GUI will only boot if it is in Recovery Mode, using the llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.1, 256 bits) graphics drivers.  Otherwise, I get a black screen with an unmoving underscore.  Starting gdm3 manually just freezes the command line interface.  Trying other display managers, like lightdm or sddm did not work.  Updating the kernel and reinstalling the drivers made no difference.

In Journalctl I keep seeing "Failed to lock front buffer on /dev/dri/card0.  systemctl says that it couldn't start xorg.

GPU is Intel a770 LE.

Thank you.